# Monotonicity of continuous functions

Tags: calculus

A Function is monotonic on $(a, b)$ and continuous on $[a, b]$, then prove that it is monotonic on $[a, b]$

Answer (score 1):

$f(b)=\lim_{x\to b^-}f(x)\geq f(t)$ for any $t\in [a,b]$

Answer (score 0):

I prove one case and you can try to promote it.

When $f(x)$ is nondecreasing in $(a,b)$ and continuous in $[a,b]$:

proof by contradiction. If $f(x)$ isn’t monotonic in $(a,b]$, now because $f(x)$ is nondecreasing in $(a,b)$
$$\therefore\exists x_0\in (a,b),f(x_0)>f(b)$$
$\because f(x)$ is continuous in $[a,b]$, $\therefore\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow b^-}f(x)=f(b)$,so
$$\because f(x_0)-f(b)>0,\therefore\exists\delta>0,\,s.t.\forall x\in (b-\delta,b),\,|f(x)-f(b)|<f(x_0)-f(b)$$
$$\therefore\forall x\in (\max\{b-\delta,x_0\},b)(now\,x>x_0),\,f(x)-f(b)\leqslant|f(x)-f(b)|<f(x_0)-f(b)\Longrightarrow f(x)<f(x_0)$$
But $f(x)$ is nondecreasing in $(a,b)$, it‘s a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Assume nondecreasing: For $t\gt s$:  $f(t)\ge f(s)$, $s,t \in (a,b)$.

Show that $f(t)\le f(b)$, for $t <b$
.
Assume there is a $t$ with $f(t)>f(b)$ , $t<b$ .

$f$ continuous on $[a,b]$.

IVT: there exist a $p \in (t,b)$ with  $f(t)>f(p)>f(b)$.

Contradiction.